# an microsoft excel csv file to be displayed on app inventor and arranging the contents

Tags: app-inventor

i have a very large CSV file in my SD card, is it possible for me to load it into app inventor and displaying it out neatly in google's appinventor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You can use the `webviewer` component and some html to import a csv file up to around 2 MB. See [here](http://puravidaapps.com/importCSV.php) for an example for the import.

And again with the `webviewer` component and some html you can display it. See [here](http://puravidaapps.com/table2.php) for an example.

[image: screnshot]

Comment: Can I make use of the tiny db component without any assistance from the web and store a .csv file with almost 2000 entries into a definition in the block builder so that I can call it out once I press a button?

Comment: For the make text part is it possible to put aa file in instead of making my own text?

Comment: I'm also wondering if I could get the information in that table and put in into a variable so I could call it out in somewhere for eg if its some set of coordinates I can call it out in maps

Comment: you can import a csv file without internet access, but there is the ~2 MB limit, just take a look at the 1st link provded. As the 2nd example is designed curently, you can't get the coordinates,it's just to display the result. I don't understand your 2nd question.

Comment: for my 2nd question im actually trying to ask how can i join my .csv file to a block so i can call it out without typing out all the information of the .csv file in the block editor and let it be displayed in either a web viewer or a label

Comment: Did you already take a look by accident at the link provided? The csv file will be converted into a list of lists. Good luck!